# Memory Configurations For Cloudera Impala

Tags: memory, hadoop, ram, impala

I'm using Impala, and I know impala does its processing in memory.  I've searched for a list of Impala configuration options, but I haven't found any thorough documentation on this, particularly with regard to memory/heap.  Does Impala have such settings?  Or does it rely on the hdfs/datanode heap space?  I know you can cap impala memory usage with `-mem_limit`, but I'm trying to better understand how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

As of the Impala 1.4.0 release, included in [CDH 5.1.0](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/cdh/cdh-5-1-0.html), Impala uses both memory and disk during query processing. To learn more about how to control Impala's use of memory, I recommend reading through the [Cloudera documentation on Impala](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_install.html), especially:

- [Using YARN Resource Management with Impala](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_resource_management.html)
- [Using HDFS Caching with Impala](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_perf_hdfs_caching.html)
- [Modifying Impala Startup Options](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_config_options.html)

You'll find more information on how to configure many aspects of Impala's memory use, including integration with HDFS caching and Hadoop YARN (via Llama). For more on HDFS caching, see [Andrew Wang and Colin McCabe's presentation from Hadoop Summit 2014](http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/inmemory-caching-in-hdfs-lower-latency-same-great-taste-33921794). For more on Llama, see [Henry Robinson's presentation from Hadoop World NYC 2013](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/100/From%20Promise%20to%20a%20Platform_%20Next%20Steps%20in%20Bringing%20Workload%20Diversity%20to%20Hadoop%20Presentation.pdf).